# Is that possible to change error message toast text?

Tags: android, robospice

I use Robospice in app which will be used in country where English is not native language.
But when I launch request and face errors (no network for example), I get toast message "No network available". Is it possible to disable toast messages or change their text?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should export the string to the strings.xml located in a values folder specific for that country.

You will need to have a folder named "values-XX" where the XX represent the two letter identifier for the country in question (i.e. for Spanish it is values-es). Inside of it you will place all the strings with the language specific translation in a new strings.xml.

Comment: No, I know this. I mean that the library launch error toasts and I don`t know how to disable them

Comment: look for the Toast inside the library and delete it.

Comment: I`ve tried to find some API to customize it, but it seems that Robospice has not any.

Answer (score 0):

You can very well change the text to be displayed in your toast message.Also you can disable it.just remove the toast from your code. for eg:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this is my Toast message!!! =)",    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

change your string to be displayed in the second argument.in the above case string displayed is `"this is my Toast message!!! =)"`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I know how to show toasts, I want to know how to customize toasts which is launched by the Robospice library